# How can I add a blank value to a Silverstripe DropDownField and require a non-blank value to be selected?

Tags: select, silverstripe

How can I add a blank value to a Silverstripe DropDownField and require a non-blank value to be selected?

Currently, my field is:

```
$myField = new DropdownField(
  'MyField',
  "So what'll it be, yes or no?",
  array( "N"=>"No", "Y"=>"Yes")
);
```

Am using SilverStripe 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set

```
$myField->setHasEmptyDefault(true);
```

And then use the [Form validation](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/tutorials/forms/#form-validation) in your controller.

Something like:

```
public function myForm() {
    $myField = new DropdownField(
        'MyField',
        "So what'll it be, yes or no?",
        array( "N"=>"No", "Y"=>"Yes")
    );
    $fields = new FieldList($myField);
    $validator = new RequiredFields('MyField');

    return new Form($this, 'myFormForm', $fields, $actions, $validator);
}
```

Comment: there is also ->setEmptyString("-- choose --")

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have assumed it wouldn't be there already! Thanks!